# LoadError: `@extend` only takes an assignment expression

Tags: julia, modelingtoolkit

I am trying to run the following code from https://docs.sciml.ai/ModelingToolkit/dev/tutorials/acausal_components/#Copy-Paste-Example

```
using ModelingToolkit, Plots, DifferentialEquations

@variables t
@connector Pin begin
    v(t)
    i(t), [connect = Flow]
end

@mtkmodel Ground begin
    @components begin
        g = Pin()
    end
    @equations begin
        g.v ~ 0
    end
end

@mtkmodel OnePort begin
    @components begin
        p = Pin()
        n = Pin()
    end
    @variables begin
        v(t)
        i(t)
    end
    @equations begin
        v ~ p.v - n.v
        0 ~ p.i + n.i
        i ~ p.i
    end
end

@mtkmodel Resistor begin
    @extend OnePort()
    @parameters begin
        R = 1.0 # Sets the default resistance
    end
    @equations begin
        v ~ i * R
    end
end
```

but I am getting the following error:

```
LoadError: `@extend` only takes an assignment expression.Got OnePort()
in expression starting at c:\Users...
```

I didn't think there would be any errors seeing as the code is copy-pasted from ModelingToolkit.jl documentation. I'm new to julia and ModelingToolkit.jl so any help is really appreciated.

Comment: Generally these errors with docs examples happen when there's a mismatch between the versions used in the docs and the version you are using locally. You're linking to the dev docs so maybe try looking at the docs for the latest released version and make sure that you have the same package version installed.